# Is there more to optimizing CSS than minimizing character count?

Tags: css, traversal, optimization

I've been reading a lot about jQuery optimization and how you can alter your selectors to cut down on the amount of DOM traversal, but I haven't heard much about CSS optimization outside of the usual minifying process. Is there any way to optimize your CSS loading/processing outside of just reducing character count and server requests?

Comment: Have you read [Reflows & Repaints: CSS Performance making your JavaScript slow?](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)

Comment: What do you mean by "reducing character count"? Removing white-space?

Comment: @Šime Yes, removing whitespace and using shorter selector statements (".home p" vs. "body .home .container p") will shrink your CSS file size and thus reduce load time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely optimise your selectors for performance. One key point is that CSS parsers read selectors right to left, whereas javascript selector engines (like jQuery etc) read them left to right. Basically though, the general principles are the same - you want each piece of the selector to match as few elements as possible, to cut down on the DOM nodes that have to be searched in order to determine a match.

That means, just like javascript, selecting a single, bare id in CSS is the fastest way you can get to an element. Selecting everything `*`, or selecting based on attributes (`[href*=foo]`) are among the slowest.

The reading order creates a difference between optimising jQuery selectors and CSS selectors: you don't gain speed by starting with an ID. For example, if you write:

```
#mainContent ul li
```

In jQuery, you are starting by finding the element with the ID mainContent, which is very fast, then digging through it's children.

In CSS, though, you are starting with all `li` elements, then looking to see if they have a `ul` ancestor, then checking if they're inside `#mainContent`. Much slower.

**Possible gains in speed**

You should also know, however, that CSS parsing is much, much faster than javascript DOM traversal - so even when you do have lots of complex, 'slow' selectors, you're unlikely to see a huge gain in performance by optimising them. Here's a good article on the increases in performance: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/ - the author points out that he could increase rendering time by about 20ms by creating a huge, complex stylesheet and document (6000 DOM elements, and 2000 CSS rules). For a more 'normal' page, your gains would therefore likely be less than 20ms - probably not worth the effort.

My view is that it's good to keep selector performance in mind while you're writing CSS, but don't let it make your stylesheets less readable or maintainable. In the majority of cases, it's not worth optimising an existing stylesheet, unless you can identify some selector that is really unnecessarily slow.

Here is some more good reading on the subject:

- http://css-tricks.com/6386-efficiently-rendering-css/
- http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Comment: Why did this answer get voted down? It was more informative (and apparently more accurate) than the other answers...

Answer (score 3):

After reading some of the resources people posted in response to this question I stumbled across this (eleven year old) gem, which is still just as helpful as it was when it was written:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS

The other big takeaway I found in my research is that you shouldn't sacrifice clean (maintainable) code or semantic best practices for CSS efficiency because the gain is so small. Still, I like my code to be clean AND efficient if at all possible, and the answers here have give me a lot to think about when writing CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make your CSS better in terms of selector matching efficiency.  By making your selectors as specific as possible, you reduce the effort needed by the HTML renderer to search the DOM for matching elements.

For example, in the cases where you know that all the spans you want to style will be direct children of the div element within your element with id #thing. it would be faster to do:

```
#thing > div > span.my-class
```

than

```
#thing span.my-class
```

because that restricts the elements that the selector has to search to find a match.

Answer (score 1):

Merging stylesheets if you have multiple (remember to keep the order right)

You can also host your static content on a different server as your application (a http server optimized for serving static content), like Lighttpd

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot to mention that.