# Should I stack css selectors with matching properties, or use shorthand for more efficient CSS?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Lately I have been stacking selectors with matching properties into one rule, thinking it's more efficient like so:

```
.logo, .menu, .format h2, .format h3, .format h4, .format h5, .format h6, #footer {
    font-family: 'Compressed Light', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 3.692307692em; /* 48px / 13px */
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

I then set the other font properties like sizing and line height in separate rules.

Would it be more efficient to use shorthand, including all the properties, even if I'll need as many rules for sizing?

```
.logo {
    font: normal small-caps 200 3.692307692em/100% 'Compressed Light', sans-serif; /* 48px / 13px */
}
```

Which style does the browser process more quickly?

Comment: "Just looking to save ms loading wherever I can." What for?

Comment: @BoltClock I'd just like answers to the specific question please. If you don't think it's worth answering, move on. I'd rather not waste my time addressing people who aren't answering the actual question I asked. You are asking me why I want to increase website performance? Really?

Comment: @JeffSebring "More efficient CSS" is very vague. Do you mean downloading time, or page-drawing, time, or ???

Comment: P.S. @BoltClock made a valid point - unless you're running a monster site with thousands of lines of CSS, and hundreds of rules, it will make little difference.

Comment: I'd rather not waste my time mulling over mere milliseconds. Ciao.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Both really. I know it will make little difference. The point of the question is to develop better habits and styles of writing css. I don't understand the people that will post to tell me my question isn't worth the time to answer because it won't make much difference. If there is no difference at all, please explain.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize performance, it is a better idea to look for [a CSS minifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier).

Just [keep your CSS readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253110/how-to-manage-css-explosion), it's more important.

If you want to lean more about CSS performance, look at this question: [Is there more to optimizing CSS than minimizing character count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341499/is-there-more-to-optimizing-css-than-minimizing-character-count). But IMHO, most of the time, the speed of a website is a matter of bandwith, not HTML/CSS parsing.

Comment: Don't use google searches in your answers, suggest a few / two you prefer, then you can suggest a search :)

Comment: This isn't an answer. It is another way to optimize that I'm already aware of. The wiki doesn't address what I'm asking.

Comment: Agree that the download differences will be trivial. A more relevant question might be which style the browser processes more quickly, but I suspect there's very little difference there as well. Follow basic rules about [efficient selectors](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/) and combine and minimize in production. Beyond that, use what is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @steveax Updated with your better formed question. Thanks.